# Chrome - OS X (10.6.4) - Full Screen option?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-chrome, fullscreen

I tried some JavaScript bookmarks (that supposedly enable the browser to go fullscreen) but they don't seem to work with Chrome. When I open Chrome on OSX it doesn't take up the full-screen (unless I do Cmd-Shift-F). Anyone know a work around besides dragging the bottom right corner to the full width of the screen?

~V

Comment: F11 works in windows, not sure about on OS X but I imagine it will be the same

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking more like the Maximize button in Windows. On OSX it only makes the window larger, but doesn't take a full screen approach. F11 on OSX brings up a different menu.

Comment: [Right Zoom](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/30591/right-zoom) is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Google Chrome, *shift-click* the Zoom button (the green `+` window button in the upper left hand corner). It will resize the window to use all available space.

Comment: Awesome. That is what I was looking for! Many thanks.

Comment: is there any way to make this the default behavior with chrome, so that i dont have to hit the shift key, like it is in firefox ?

Comment: Wow! Been wondering how to expand Chrome without using the resize corner for over a year! Thanks @Daniel Beck!!

Comment: This option is under "Maximizes the window" in the docs for Mac keyboard shortcuts: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Help` menu. In the search box at the top, type `Full Screen`.

The top hit will be a menu item; if you hover over it, OS X will pop up the `View` menu to show you the `Enter Full Screen` menu item, and you'll see that the keyboard shortcut is `shift-command-f`